# How can i change status bar text color, depending on theme android

Tags: android, android-theme, android-statusbar, android-night-mode

I have a problem. In day theme i have a light status bar background and dark text, but if i change theme to night, the status bar background becomes dark and text becomes dark, but i need the text to become light. How can i do this?

Screenshots below:

[image: light]

[image: dark]

v23\themes code:

```
<style name="Theme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/action_bar</item> // this color looks like background
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
</style>
```

night-v23\themes code:

```
<style name="Theme.Night" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/action_bar</item> // this color looks like background
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I've tested your updates Code and it seems to work on my side. You'r not over ruling  something somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Android Project you can change those values inside your `themes.xml`, there should be two of them, One for Day Theme and one for Night Theme.

In those files you can change al the default colors that Android wil use.

You can find the themes.xml inside '`app`' > '`res`' > '`values`' > '`themes.xml`'

For more info is there also this use full answer; https://imstudio.medium.com/android-change-status-bar-text-color-659680fce49b

[image]

[image]

Comment: I already have these two files. i have tried to use `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` in v23/theme and `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>` in night-v23/theme, but the text is still dark in night mode

Comment: I'm going to take a look at it in Android Studio. Will come back to you!

Comment: I just updated the post and added the code from v23\themes.xml and night-v23\themes.xml, maybe it will be useful

Comment: I've tested your updates Code and it seems to work on my side. You'r not over ruling something somewhere else?

Comment: maybe, maybe, but i can upload my project on github and give you a link, ok? maybe there is some problem that I don't see :)

Comment: Do you need all the different themes.xml with specific api levels? Otherwise I will advise to have only one themes for night and only one day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235563/discussion-between-sector-and-j-quest).